# How to add class to the parent div

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I have set the max-width of the parent to 91%. I want to add class to the parent div if the children components of the div crosses the max-width of the Parent div i.e 91%.

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: That looks like AngularJS. Why did you add the Angular2 tag?

Comment: sorry by mistake i added i guess i am looking for angularjs1 solution . I will remove tag immediately